# How to put a clickable icon inside a button in android

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I want to put a settings icon to the right of a full-width button which when clicked opens an alert dialog box and allows users to set sound as ringtone or notification tone.

I want tiny clickable icons like these to the right of my button;
[image]

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this layout and set onClickListener on ImageView
You can also set another clickListener on TextView to do another action.
All together it will look like one button.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/zxc"
              android:text="Example"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/zxc"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/ic_comment"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_payment"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/share_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is  a samplt text"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/share_btn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button mShareButton;
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mShareButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share_btn);
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.share_txt);
    mShareButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.share_btn:
            Log.i("Test"," Button clicked");
            break;

        case R.id.share_txt:
            Log.i("Test"," Text clicked");
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can I set an Onclick method on share_icon ?

Comment: So you want the click to be only on the icon ? Your question says put icon inside button which will give click event to entire button (text and icon)

Comment: Yes, I need to have seperate click methods for the main button and for the small share_icon. The click on main button is for playing the audio and the click on share_icon will be for sharing the audio or setting it as a ringtone

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by using a Linear Layout with orientation set to horizontal and weight sum of 10. Inside the linear layout, I created a Button with width of match parent and layout_weight of 10 and then created a ImageButton for the small bell icon with width set to wrap content and layout_weight set to 0. I had to set the height and background for both the button and ImageButton as same that is 50sp and #6465a5 in my case.
Thanks everyone for the help. Complete beginner here. :D

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="#6465A5"
            android:fontFamily="@font/shadowsintolight"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:onClick="translate"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:tag="themostamazingthings"
            android:text="THE MOST AMAZING THINGS"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bell1"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bell"
            android:background="#6465A5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="bellClick"
            android:tag="themostamazingthings"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```